# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}|f_n(x)| \, dx= 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions and $g: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be an increasing and continuous function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$.

We also have that

(i) $\int_0^1|f_n(x)|g(|f_n(x)|)\,dx < 100$

(ii) $ f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere

We must show that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 |f_n(x)| \, dx = 0$$

What I have:

Let $\epsilon > 0$,

$g$ is continuous and increasing, then

$$ \exists M > 0, g(|f_n(x)|) > M \mbox{ and } \frac{100}{M} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Now consider the following partition of $[0,1]$

$$E_1 = \{x \in [0,1]: |f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{M}\}$$
$$E_2 = \{x \in [0,1]: |f_n(x)| > \frac{1}{M}\}$$

Then 
$$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|\,dx = \int_{E_1}|f_n(x)| + \int_{E_2}|f_n(x)| \, dx$$

Thus,

\begin{align}
& \left|\int_0^1|f_n(x)|\,dx\right| < \frac{1}{M}m(E_1) + \int_0^1 |f_n(x)| \frac{g(|f_n(x)|)}{g(|f_n(x)|)} \, dx \\[10pt]
< {} & \frac{1}{M} + \frac{1}{M} \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|g(|f_n(x)|) \, dx < \frac{100}{M} + \frac{100}{M} < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{align}

I want to know if I got the proof right. Thanks.

Comment: You lost me at the line "$g$ is continuous and increasing, then [...]." Can you explain what you argue there?

Comment: $g$ is a fixed function: the fact that it's an increasing function doesn't mean that "it goes to infinity at every point" (such statement does not even mean anything), which I guess is what you seem to say.

Comment: To clarify, take $g(x)=x$ in the question, and check your proof with this specific instance. (This $g$ is indeed strictly increasing, so satisfies the assumption.)

Comment: @RichardClare: I feel confused about your question now. What if we assume $g$ is constant 0? That means the first condition doesn't exist. But obviously, condition 2 is not enough for the conclusion. I guess $g$ should be strictly increasing.

Comment: @XIAODAQU In English, the convention is that "increasing" means "strictly increasing" (otherwise, it is "non-decreasing"). It makes little sense, but anyway...

Comment: @ClementC.: Alright then. The poster has edited the problem. Looks solvable now.

Comment: Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, then we can choose a enough large $M$ such that $\frac{100}{g(M)}<\varepsilon/2$. And seperate the $[0,1]$ with this $M$.

Comment: I eliminate the egoroff theorem because I find that it is unnecessary.  What do you think?

Comment: No, I think Egoroff is still necessary. I'll write a correct proof as an answer. You need to separate the set into three parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall \varepsilon>0$

$\exists M>0,\ s.t.\ 100/g(M)<\varepsilon/3$.

Due to Egoroff. $\exists E(measurable)\subset[0, 1]\ \&\ m([0, 1]-E)<\varepsilon/(3M)$. And $f_n\xrightarrow{u.}0$ on E.

Find an enough large N such that $\forall n>N$, $|f_n|<\varepsilon/3$ on E.

Then we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1|f_n|dx&=&\int_E|f_n|dx+\int_{[0, 1]-E}|f_n|dx\\
&\leq&\varepsilon/3+\int_{([0, 1]-E)\cap\{|f_n|\leq M\}}|f_n|dx+\int_{([0, 1]-E)\cap\{|f_n|> M\}}|f_n|dx\\
&\leq&\varepsilon/3+\int_{[0, 1]-E}Mdx+\int_{[0, 1]\cap\{|f_n|>M\}}|f_n|dx\\
&\leq&2\varepsilon/3+\int_{[0, 1]\cap\{|f_n|>M\}}|f_n|\frac{g(|f_n|)}{g(|f_n|)}dx\\
&\leq&2\varepsilon/3+\frac{1}{g(M)}\int_0^1|f_n|g(|f_n|)dx\\
&\leq&\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Now everything makes sense to me. Thank you!!

Comment: Hey, I want to ask you something. The Egoroff theorem says that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]\setminus E$.  $|f_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ in $[0,1]\setminus E$ not in E. ... I now have my doubts.

Comment: @RichardClare: I don't quite understand what you mean...but I think you've taken my "$[0, 1]-E$" as your "$E$". Maybe in your statement, $f_n$ are uniformly converges in $[0, 1]-E$ and $m(E)<\varepsilon$. I just express them oppositely. It's all the same.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.